# How can I truncate text in a div or cell as the browser resizes

Tags: css, resize, css-tables

I have a row consisting of icon/text/timestamp in the header section of my HTML page. I want to have the icon and the timestamp of this row remain at a fixed width, and when the browser resizes, I want to reduce the size of the text div (table-cell) by having an ellipsis appear. While I can get the ellipsis to appear with a fixed width, I want the width of the text div (table-cell) to be 100% until the browser gets smaller, then I want this text div to get smaller and for the ellipsis to appear as this div shrinks.

I could solve this problem with media queries, or a directive to resize dynamically, but I was hoping that HTML/CSS could solve it.

Is this possible?

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/em83B/

```
<div style="display: table; table-layout: fixed;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; background: pink; min-width: 60px;">
        AAA
    </div>

    <div style="display: table-cell; background: yellow; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; min-width: 300px; max-width: 600px;">
        This is the text I want to have truncated as the browser resizes
    </div>

    <div style="display: table-cell; background: lightblue; min-width: 100px;">
        CCC
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wound up solving this with bootstrap columns. I put the icon and text into one div where class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-7" and then I put the timestamp in the other div with class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-5". That seems to be good enough, but not perfect. If there are any better suggestions, I would like to hear them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`text-overflow: ellipsis` works only when you've also set `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: Thanks. I already have that in the style for the middle div (the one I want to resize). I assume it does not need to be anywhere else in this example.

Comment: You also need to set a width on the div that has `display: table` (as long as `table-layout: fixed`, which is commented out in your fiddle, is restored). It will size up the other columns too, though. So set up proper widths for them too.