# Truncate text with css

Tags: html, css

I've got this problem with text truncating. It doesn't truncate when I'm trying to size down the winow. The filed with the LONG TEXT shrinks until the button meets the last letter in it and doesn't go further to truncate. No three-dot thing just stops at the last letter inside the field. Somewhat like this - [image]

I have something like this in html layout:

In all other

```css
.Label:not(textarea){
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.input-group-btn {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="field_19" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" id="field_18" value="456">
    <span class="Label" title="Some Text">SOME LONG LONG LONG LONG TEXT</span>
    <span class="input-group-btn ev-input-group input-group">
        <button type="button" class="edit_button" data-reditcontroller="some url">btn
            <i class="f-edit"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by truncating? Should the text vanish?

Comment: @IU5er Just the part that doesn't fit inside a smaller window

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489780/how-can-i-truncate-text-in-a-div-or-cell-as-the-browser-resizes

Answer (score 6):

The reason for the strange behavior is that you have not defined the WIDTH at which the `...` should start. And make sure it is `display:inline-block` so as to make sure the width is definable.

### CSS

```
  .Label:not(textarea){
      overflow:hidden;
      width: 90%; //can also use calc function as per Yudi's answer
      display: inline-block;
      text-overflow:ellipsis;
      white-space:nowrap;
    }
```

Comment: The thing is that the width must adapt to the window size. It must change.

Comment: @JDoeBloke there are various ways to do that. If the dom is taking the full width, then you can use percentage to make it responsive. You can also use as per Yudi Chang's answer. Mine would be responsive if you use it within grid systems as well. But make sure that when using my codes, you also have a wrapper over it which has 100% width :)

Comment: @JDoeBloke oh and i have edited to as per requirements.

Comment: @JDoeBloke [measuring Width in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Label:not(textarea){
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: calc(100vw - 45px);
    display: block;
}

.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.input-group-btn {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="field_19" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" id="field_18" value="456">
    <span class="Label" title="Some Text">SOME LONG LONG LONG LONG TEXT</span>
    <span class="input-group-btn ev-input-group input-group">
        <button type="button" class="edit_button" data-reditcontroller="some url">btn
            <i class="f-edit"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Label:not(textarea){
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
  width:150px;
}

.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.input-group-btn {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="field_19" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" id="field_18" value="456">
    <span class="Label" title="Some Text">SOME LONG LONG LONG LONG TEXT</span>
    <span class="input-group-btn ev-input-group input-group">
        <button type="button" class="edit_button" data-reditcontroller="some url">btn
            <i class="f-edit"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Restrict the `.Label`'s width, so it fits inside the window with `max-width: 100%`.
2. In order for the above to work, you need to set `display` on `.Label` to `block` or `inline-block`. The closest to what you already have is `inline-block`.
3. Remove `display: table` from the `.input-group`. I assume it's not really necessary here, because you using `div` instead of `table`.

```css
.Label:not(textarea) {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.input-group-btn {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="hidden" id="field_19" value="123">
  <input type="hidden" id="field_18" value="456">
  <span class="Label" title="Some Text">SOME LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG TEXT</span>
  <span class="input-group-btn ev-input-group input-group">
        <button type="button" class="edit_button" data-reditcontroller="some url">btn
            <i class="f-edit"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```