# How to truncate a string with ellipsis on two lines React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to truncate a string on two lines with an ellipsis, but I don't know the exact length of the cut because the div that contains the string can have different widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a non-standard but pretty well supported [CSS property `-webkit-line-clamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp) that does it. It has some drawbacks in cases where the text has nested HTML elements in it, but gives decent result it simple cases.

There are also React plugins for this like react-dotdotdot or react-truncate, but they also have some issues (e.g. need to control the resizing of the container).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `text-overflow: ellipses`? Here are the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

In this [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489780/how-can-i-truncate-text-in-a-div-or-cell-as-the-browser-resizes) @StevenDon suggests to also set `white-space: nowrap` in addition to `text-overflow: ellipses`